# iMac FaceTime HD camera shows no image/black image

Tags: mac, imac, camera

There's an iMac whose FaceTime HD camera isn't displaying video images in applications like FaceTime, Photo Booth, or QuickTime video recorder.

OS X El Cap shows that the camera is attached and registered properly in the About This Mac - System Report.

- fresh new install of El Cap on a Fusion drive. Previously the camera worked well with Yosemite.
- the green light indicator flashes on/off repeatedly and irregularly when you start an application that uses the camera
- there are no error messages or anything about no cameras being attached.
- pressing the big button to take a photo in Photo Booth has no effect. The button is on the screen, but isn't pressable.
- Skype is not installed

What steps can I take to get the camera to capture and display video properly?

[image]

**Attempts to fix**

- [reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204063)

**Items to investigate**

- should I [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)?
- will the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201257) reveal anything

I recently [opened this iMac to install an SSD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1p3B4bWZNA). All cables were re-attached properly.

[image]

Comment: The green LED should stay solid when the camera is recording. Your troubleshooting clues: the LED flashes & you get no image, and that you recently cracked the case and played around inside, is an indication that either some of the cables were _not_ attached correctly, not fully seated, or some other damage went down whilst the iMac was open.

Comment: None of this worked for me. I also put in an sdd and made a Fusion drive. I also upgraded the RAM from 4 to 6 GB... The camera is working, and does go off when I quit the app that should use it. There is no missing camera message. Green light is constantly on. Photo boot remains dark, skype simply keeps looking for the camera, waiting for the picture to come on.

Comment: Wait, what's this about Skype? I have it installed but it's not running (according to `ps aux | grep -i skype`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) solved the camera issue. It's now working as per normal.

All that involves is shutting down the machine, removing all power from the computer for 15 seconds, and restoring power.

Answer (score 47):

I have had this problem in the past. I found my answer here. http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/27/fix-there-is-no-connected-camera-error-mac/

Open terminal from the utilities folder in the applications folder. Type `sudo killall VDCAssistant` into terminal and click enter.
Then, enter `sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant` (may say "No matching processes were found", this should be fine). That should do the trick.

Comment: My camera stops working. I google all over the place, and find various ideas of broken cables and faulty El Capitan upgrades. Then all of a sudden your answer comes up, not voted up even once. I follow the two steps. And the camera works. Thank you.

Comment: @Paolo you're welcome! :) I was googling everywhere too. I guess I got lucky with the article I found.

Comment: $ sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant
No matching processes were found.! Any idea why

Comment: @KunalPanchal hmm... my first suggestion would be to copy and paste directly into terminal (in case of a misspelling) but that probably won't fix it. Next, I would check activity monitor for the process and try quitting it from there. If that doesn't work, reboot and try everything again. Hope this helps!

Comment: @cavalcade no problem!

Comment: I got the same `no matching processes were found` error but just killing the VDC Assistant did the trick.

Comment: @kgrote not sure why AppleCameraAssistant isn't a running process. My guess is that both killall statements fix the issue for different problems. They are both safe to run no matter what though. Glad it worked anyway!

Comment: This did the trick for me. I first tried resetting the SMC but that didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: First command worked for me

Comment: sudo killall VDCAssistant still solving this issue on Mojave.

Comment: In my case `sudo killall VDCAssistant` works perfectly

Comment: I love you. `sudo killall VDCAssistant` did the trick. Lifesaver 1 minute before important video call! Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: `sudo killall VDCAssistant` works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with my Mac - the screen was completely black when trying to use the camera for Skype etc. Simply rebooting and unplugging my computer, closing all apps, empty the cache, fixed the problem instantly!

Answer (score -2):

> sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant

Comment: Providing more than a command would be useful. FWIW, some askers might not know where to input the command.

Answer (score -2):

works for me after i remove icloud drive.[image]